# How to implement cancel and submit button inside angular material extended mde popover

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a small form with 'cancel' and 'submit' button inside the popover. i am trying to close the popover after the user submit the form. i tried many ways which is explained in the popover. unfortunately it didn't work. is there any work around on this scenario?

```
<button class="mdc-fab app-fab--absolute"  
     [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="appPopover"
      mdePopoverTriggerOn="click" aria-label="Favorite" mat-fab ><mat-icon>
     <span class="mdc-fab__icon material-icons">textsms</span> 
  </mat-icon></button>   

  <mde-popover #appPopover="mdePopover" [mdePopoverOverlapTrigger]="false">

      <input type ="text"......./>

      <button (click)="submit()">submit</button>
      <button (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
  </mde-popover>
```

I am using this plugin
https://github.com/material-extended/mde

Comment: 1. That control is in alpha currently and looks like it is in just the beginning stages. I wouldn't use it for any sort of production site. 2. What, exactly, did you try? I don't see any attempt to close the popover in your code. Is `submit()` doing something to that end? 3. Have you tried submitting an issue [here](https://github.com/material-extended/mde/issues)?

Comment: `  <button mat-raised-button color="primary"
    [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="appPopover" mdePopoverTriggerOn="click" [mdePopoverCloseOnClick]="flag"> Show Popover</button> <mde-popover #appPopover="mdePopover">
    <mat-card style="max-width: 300px">
      <mat-card-content>
      A material design popover component created using Angular version 6 with the Angular CDK.
      </mat-card-content>
      <button (click)="cancelPopover($event)">Cancel</button>
    </mat-card>
  </mde-popover>
in TS file
  flag = false
  cancelPopover(e){
    this.flag = true
  }`

Comment: @Dean 
Posted the same issue in github also 
https://github.com/material-extended/mde/issues/31